# Webpack doesn't load HTML

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I get 404 not found error when loading the HTML page with webpack.
These are my configurations.

Webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports= {
    devServer: {
        // contentBase
        static : {
          directory : path.join(__dirname, 'public/')
        },
        port: 3000,
        // publicPath
        devMiddleware:{
           publicPath: 'https://localhost:3000/dist/',
        },
        // hotOnly
        hot: 'only',
      },
};
```

The other file configurations are on the screenshot.
The webpack server runs correctly, but when I try to load the page I get this error.
Please tell me where I am wrong.

Screenshot of the other files. [image: webpackProblem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your `index.html` in the right place in your `/public` folder?

From the **webpack** docs:

> To load your bundled files, you will need to create an `index.html` file
> in the build folder from which static files are served (--content-base
> option).

Or try put this in `webpack.config.js`:

```
 devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

Or sometimes you could need to point out your **historyApiFallback** `index.html` file like this:

```
 devServer: {
        historyApiFallback:{
            index:'build/index.html'
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem was that I didn't have a public folder, so I just deleted the /public from the directory property, and I added historyApiFallback: true, everything is running now.